# Parity of Particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, elementary-particles, parity

Like charge, spin,etc.. Parity is an intrinsic property of the particle. As I read in Grifith's introduction to elementary particles book , he states parity mathematically but I am not able to see it physically, for vectors we invert, so what do we do for particles when applying the parity operator on them ?